# Event needed on computed field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field (Total) that has a computed value.

This is the control source: =[FrmSupplierQuote].[Form].[TotalSupplierCost]

This field is updating just fine when the subform is updated

When this field updates I wish to execute the subroutine that updates the field FinalPrice:

```
Public Sub Update_FinalPrice()
   Me.FinalPrice = Round((Me.Total * (1 + Me.Markup)), 2) 
End Sub
```

I've tried the events On Change, After Update and On Dirty with no luck. I'm wondering if I've taken the correct approach here and I'm open to suggestions as to how to make this work. I was wondering if I should be driving it from the subForm. I have another form like this that has two subForms.

Comment: You name three events, but you don't say of WHICH form component. The form and all editable controls have all those events, so you have the choice of using the form-level events, or control-level events. I would put this kind of update in the AfterUpdate event of the controls bound to the fields used in the calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have actually attached a subroutine to the After Update event for the controls. Do you know which event triggers computed fields to be updated?

Comment: That's a difficult question. There's no event for calculated controls, as not data is changing. I think they'd change based on the Refresh interval, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be clearer in your question as to where the input goes, but presuming the input goes in the subform, then:

1. The parent form will never after update or change or be dirty as it is the subform that gets dirty, changes and updates.
2. In the subform's relevant event (I am not sure how you compute the parents "Me.Total", so its not clear which event to use) you can call the Update_FinalPrice sub in the parent form.
3. This design is nice, because the parent form doesn't need to know the nature of the subform it holds.  All it has to do is expose a public Sub that does the work.  The onus is then on the subforms to call this sub using their Parent property.
4. I would write an Update_All method in the parent form and the subform just calls this for all purposes.  It might take a bit of refactoring, but you would end up with a simpler app.  Otherwise you will be faffing around with any number of combinations of when to calculate the total, when to calculate the final price, etc, etc.  Note the maintenance, not development, is the highest cost of software.  If badly designed, a lot of that cost *should* be yours:  it is not the client's fault that you got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that, you ckarified what I thought in point 1/ about the events.

Comment: Retype: Thanks for that, you clarified what I thought in point 1/ about the events. For point 2/ Me.Total is a field on the parent form that is not on the underlying table hence I use =[FrmSupplierQuote].[Form].[TotalSupplierCost] to update it, I'd like to know what event causes this it look like 'Dirty' on the subform. I'll do a call 'up' from the subform to resolve my issues. Please note that I am more than aware of maintenance issues, my problem is that I am iteratively developing with the customer, so the design is fluid

Comment: I know the iterative feeling.  Had it today in fact with a website...  Just checking really, as VBA doesn't really encourage Patterns and Practices like more modern languages do.  You just have to try and think that way

Comment: How do I call 'up'? Tried Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
 Dim parentForm As Access.Form
 Set parentForm = Me.Parent
 Call parentForm.UpdateFinalPrice
End Sub

Comment: Don't worry, fixed the spelling error! and called using Me.Parent.Update_FinalPrice , thanks for your help. I think I've been spoilt using modern languages, used to carry it all in my head when I used a pencil!